# increase /dev directory size inside pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I googled , but didn't get any solution to this.

Q: in k8s/gke node version 1.12.10-XX:  the /dev directory size inside a pod, come around half of the underlying node memory size.

where as in latest version it comes fix only 64M. But I want a larger size of /dev inside my pod.

Comment: Usually `/dev` contains only device "special files", directory entries with special handling by the kernel; you wouldn't have any actual storage there.  What's your use case for needing larger (or any) space in `/dev`?

Comment: We are using one third-party application  (ABBYY  FC) where it needs a larger size of /dev and /dev/shm. In older k8s , by defult /dev was coming bigger size i.e half of node memory. But in newer node versions it's fixed to 64M only.

Comment: do we speak about nodes with "Container-Optimized OS from Google" ?

Comment: yep. we just pick what the gke defaults.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an open [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/issues/114) about that on GoogleCloudPlatform's github issue tracker. The issue has been created in late Feb.

I suggest adding "+1" there by leaving a comment and monitoring the progress.

Comment: he is one of my team mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm that isn't working using Container-Optimized OS (cos) 1.14.10-gke.27 (master version)

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test1
  name: test1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test1
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: demo
        emptyDir:
          medium: Memory
          sizeLimit: "1Gi"
      containers:
      - name: busy
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "sleep 3000"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: demo
          mountPath: /dev/shm
```

It's 1,8Gi ~= 0.5 the underlying node memory size

---

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  94.3G      2.9G     91.4G   3% /
tmpfs                     1.8G         0      1.8G   0% /dev/shm
```

Please [note](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/63126?spm=a2c65.11461447.0.0.37da3505CmUORW#issuecomment-387817170)

> the sizeLimit parameter set for emptyDir works differently (in this release at the moment) - eviction manager keeps monitoring the disk space used by pod emptyDir volume and it will evict pods when the usage exceeds the limit.

```
   medium       <string>
     What type of storage medium should back this directory. The default is ""
     which means to use the node's default medium. Must be an empty string
     (default) or Memory

   sizeLimit    <string>
     Total amount of local storage required for this EmptyDir volume. The size
     limit is also applicable for memory medium. 

     The maximum usage on memory medium EmptyDir would be the minimum value
     between the SizeLimit specifiedhere and the sum of memory limits of all
     containers in a pod. The default is nil which means that the limit is
     undefined
```

Hope this help.